# How to print an image over several sheets of paper

Tags: images, printing

I want to print a single image that will ultimately be almost 2 metres high, and it's perfectly all right for me to do so by printing several A3 sheets of paper and gluing them onto a big piece of cardboard. How should I go about this? (I'm on Windows XP.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Poster Printer**](http://posterprinter.sourceforge.net/) works with your existing printer to allow you to print documents at a much larger size than would fit on a single printed page

[image]

(open source, Windows)

Comment: Thanks! However, it keeps failing with "The Printer returned an error" and it will not let me print anything. Have you come across that before?

Comment: nope, works fine for me whenever i print a banner.

Comment: I think it was that it was a network printer. I ended up just printing to PDF using CutePDF and then printing from that. Works great, thanks!

Comment: you're more than welcome.

Comment: I didn't try anything funky other than running the .exe as admin, but this wouldn't install on Windows 7.

Comment: I guess this software is outdated - the [installator crashes](http://pasteboard.co/2YyJoLr.png) during the process.

Answer (score 3):

[PosteRazor](http://posterazor.sourceforge.net/) cuts a raster image into pieces which can afterwards be printed out and assembled to a poster.  PosteRazor is open source and is available for Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux.

Comment: +1 This worked pretty well on Windows 7, although it didn't like my PNG so I had to convert it to JPEG first.

Comment: Aparently, they have updated it - I had no problems with my PNG file.

Answer (score 1):

Use rasterbator http://homokaasu.org/rasterbator/

Comment: Online interface is great, but is there a way to keep the original image rather than turning it into dot version?

Comment: Also, it forces various effect on images - simple splitting is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

[LibreOffice Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc). Drag and drop your image to the Calc. Adjust page and print settings (in print preview), remove unnecessary headers, footers and etc. Print.

I also tried to do the same with Excel, but it ignores the drag and drop of an image and ignores image DPI when inserting the image from file.