# How can I print one page enlarged to multiple pages?

Tags: pdf, printing

Is there a way using Adobe's Reader software to print a single PDF file page enlarged onto several physical pages?

I know there are special "poster" printing packages, and that sometimes a printer driver will allow it, but I am wondering of there is a way to do it from Adobe Reader directly without an outside dependency.

Comment: I hate to completely ignore the "without an outside dependency" part of the question but I have used rasterbator on occasion and it's pretty slick. http://homokaasu.org/rasterbator/

Comment: Thanks for the link.. i've seen it but that "without an outside dependency" part is kinda important.  :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I know this is old, but just in case people come across this on Google, Adobe Reader X can do it now.  Just select "Poster" mode when printing and scale it accordingly.

Foxit also has that mode, but I found that it doesn't work if the PDF has a plugin, for example the Mindjet plugin.

Answer (score 10):

[Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com) is a free PDF reader that supports tiled printing.

(I know you're asking about no external dependencies, but this question is also a first-page result on Google, hopefully this will help others without that requirement.)

Comment: I'm having trouble getting all pages to print; my large page is tiled over 12 pages (at 25% zoom), but 4-6 pages aren't printing (tho not always the same pages).

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible in Adobe's free Reader but is possible in Adobe's commercial Acrobat Pro:

Go to the Print dialog box and set Page Scaling to **Tile all pages** (on v 10.1.4 of Acrobat Pro, you may have to first select **Page Size & Handling** --> **Poster**). You can then adjust the **Tile Scale** to a suitable percentage. You should be able to see how many physical pages will be used in the print preview.

Comment: Hmm... I don't see that option.  What version are you using?

Comment: @nonot1: I'm using Acrobat Pro 9.0.0. I just installed Reader 9.4.0 in a VM and confirmed that it DOES NOT have the option I mentioned. Sorry.

Comment: can make that an official answer?

Comment: @notot1: I've edited my answer to make it more conclusive. Cheers.

Comment: Works in Acrobat Reader Free.

Answer (score 3):

It's not quite what you're after but after seeing you hit a brick wall with native support perhaps it may be of use.

Have you looked at this? [Multi-Page PDF Banner/Poster from PDF](https://superuser.com/questions/45831/multi-page-pdf-banner-poster-from-pdf)

If you save the PDF as an image then you can use PostorRazor on the image to print across spanned pages.
Hope it helps.