# How can I print text as a large picture (poster) using only A3 pages?

Tags: images

I need to print a selection of text so that it is possible to read it from across a room. I thought the best thing would be to print it like a poster, but the largest our printer can print is size A3. The picture would have to be scaled and split and then the A3 pages put together. Is there software available for this? I looked at Rasterbator but I only get dots.

Comment: I used http://posterazor.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=download&lang=english. The text is not very pretty after scaling but you can't have everything I suppose :-)

Answer (score 0):

Note: OP used http://posterazor.sourceforge.net/ as explained in the comments, but he was unhappy with the results of scaling.

If the text is printed to size using Word or a similar program, the scaling should be perfect with almost every font. This image should be saved to a pdf, via Bullzip or another pdf printer.

Examples given here:
[How to print an image over several sheets of paper](https://superuser.com/questions/38819/how-to-print-an-image-over-several-sheets-of-paper?rq=1) should help once you've got the image sized properly.